# CakePHP - Issue with Deleting Data via a Link

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.0.
What I'm trying to do is have the user click a link (in the form of an image) and that user action would delete some data from the database for that user.

In my view, I have this code snippet, which is actually a column in a table. For the word 'delete', I want that to be an image (using $this->Html->image()), but cakephp complains about that. According to the API, that parameter can only be a string.

```
$this->Form->postLink(
                'delete', 
                array('action' => 'deleteActivity', $myActivity['Activity']['id']),
                array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')),
```

Here is my function in my controller that I'm attempting:

```
public function deleteActivity($id) {

        if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {             
            $this->Session->setFlash('The activity with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'landingPage'));
        }
    }
```

I get the error below. Appears that wrapping a form tag with post isn't going to work. Is what I'm trying to do the best practice way of doing this, in CakePHP?

Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<td><form action="/activities/index.php/activities/deleteActivity/4"      name="post_515496f40ca77" id="post_515496f40ca77" style="display:none;" method="post">    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></form><a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;Are you sure?&#039;)) { document.post_515496f40ca77.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The error:**

The error basically says "Hey, there's no such thing as the `Post` object, so we're not sure what to do with this 'delete' method you're trying to access" (in other words, the `Post` model isn't yet loaded)

**Further explanation / solution:**

You don't inherently have access to models other than the one who's controller you're currently in.

So in your case, you cannot directly access the `Post` model without either loading it:

```
$this->loadModel('Post');
$this->Post->delete($id);
```

or, if it's associated with the current model (eg. `Activity`), you can access it through that like this:

```
$this->Activity->Post->delete($id);
```

Comment: Based on the information in the question, my guess is that the OP is trying to delete the Activity itself, so it should be `$this->Activity->delete($id);`

Comment: @thaJeztah - that's possible, but the id of the item is 'post_515496f40ca77', and his code is `$this->Post->delete()`, so... not sure.  Either way, this explains the error, and if he wanted Activity instead, it should point him right to what needs changed.

Comment: I had a delay in getting back to this. Thanks for your comments. The issue was staring me in the face the whole time. The dreaded copy/paste error. Yes, instead of 'Post', I should have had 'Activity' in my controller. Once I made that change, then it worked. Now I just need to figure out how to display an image instead of text (for the user to click on the link).